# Approximating a three-times differentiable function by a linear combination of derivatives

Tags: calculus

Let $\,f$ be three times differentiable on the interval $[a, b]$. Show that there is a $c$ such that:
$$f(b) - f(a) = \frac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)+f'(b)) - \frac{(b-a)^3}{12}f'''(c).$$
Answered in the comments.

Comment: This looks similar to a Taylor's Theorem problem, but you need to be clever, since the second-derivative term is missing from above. But there should be a way around that.

Comment: I am surprised to see the simple trapezoidal rule for integration coming up in so many forms. Put $g(x)=f'(x)$ and then you have $$\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx=\frac{b-a}{2}\cdot\{g(a)+g(b)\} -\frac{(b-a)^{3}}{12}g''(c)$$ and a proof is available at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/535304/72031

Comment: In reality it is $f'''(s_1)$ and $f'''(s_2)$, and not  two times $f'''(s)$ with the same $s$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that uses Rolle's theorem. Let

\begin{equation}
g(x) = f(a) + \frac{x - a}{2}(f'(a) + f'(x)) - R(x - a)^3, \quad x\in [a,b].
\end{equation}

Here, $R$ is the constant that makes $f(b) = g(b)$. Note that $g(a) = f(a)$, $g'(a) = f'(a)$ and $g''(a) = f''(a)$. Set $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then $h(a) = h(b) = 0$, hence $h'(c_1) = 0$ for some $c_1\in (a,b)$. Since $h'(a) = 0$ and $h'(c_1) = 0$, $h''(c) = 0$ for some $c\in (a,c_1)$. Thus $f''(c) = g''(c)$, or

\begin{equation}
f''(c) = f''(c) + \frac{c - a}{2}f'''(c) - 6R(c - a).
\end{equation}

Simplifying this equation results in

\begin{equation}
R = \frac{f'''(c)}{12}.
\end{equation}

Thus

\begin{equation}
f(b) - f(a) = g(b) - f(a) = \frac{b - a}{2}(f'(a) + f'(b)) - \frac{(b - a)^3}{12}f'''(c).
\end{equation}