# $f(b)-f(a) =((b-a)/2)\cdot(f'(a)+f'(b))-((b-a)³/12)\cdot f'''(c)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be three times differentiable on $[a,b]$. $f'''$ is continuous. Show that there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $$f(b)-f(a) =((b-a)/2)\cdot(f'(a)+f'(b))-((b-a)³/12)\cdot f'''(c)$$

This looks like a combination of Mean Value Theorem and Taylor's series. but how to solve it, i don't know.
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: There is a typo. You must have $f'(a) + f'(b)$ instead of $f'(a) - f'(b)$. Check with $f(x) = x$. And then it is same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008049/approximating-a-three-times-differentiable-function-by-a-linear-combination-of-d

Comment: I have edited the question as per my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use
$$ f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)(x-a)^2+\frac{1}{6}f'''(c_1)(x-a)^3$$
and
$$ f(x)=f(b)+f'(b)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(b)(x-b)^2+\frac{1}{6}f'''(c_2)(x-b)^3$$
for $x=b$ and $x=a$ respectively.