# Mathematical proof for the trapezoidal rule?

Tags: calculus

Could someone supply a mathematical proof of the following rule:

$$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx \approx (b-a) \left[ \dfrac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} \right]$$

that doesn't rely on partitions as I'm not comfortable with them yet?

Comment: http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~etalvila/talks/talvilaboston2.pdf, http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151A/hw6/Numerical_Integration.pdf

Comment: There is nothing to add. (+1).

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It's a very nice question

Comment: @Liam: Could you please clarify what "$\approx$" means here? (The formal answer to your question is "calculate the area enclosed by the secant line through $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$", but without a precise definition of the relation symbol it's impossible to be more specific.)

Comment: I suspect the word "proof" is causing the downvotes. I would change the word "proof" to "explanation".

Comment: @étale-cohomology I edited it, but at first it was just a reference to some image on Wikipedia which may have caused the downvotes at the start.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang They probably intend it to mean approximately, they posted this with a reference to the image containing the formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Comment: Alright, thank you Andrew!

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535304/72031

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek: Without a definition of "approximately", we have $x \approx y$ for all real $x$ and $y$. (In practice, the integral of $f$ over $[a, b]$ can differ from the right-hand side by an arbitrarily large amount.)

Answer (score 4):

*This isn't necessarily a proof per se*, but perhaps will shed some insight on why they are approximately equal.

So the area of a trapezoid is given by $\dfrac{b_1+b_2}{2} \cdot h$, where

[image]

So now looking at some functions graph and noting the placement of $a,b,f(a),$ and $f(b)$ (where I chose $a$ and $b$ arbitrarily) you can see how the trapezoid begins to form:

[image]

and how its area *very closely* approximates the proper area under the curve (integral). Now using the points that I've labeled on our functions graph and the formula of a trapezoid, the area would come out to be:

$$\dfrac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} \cdot (b-a)$$

(Note that our trapezoid is sort of "on it's side" in the photo, as the height of it is $(b-a)$.)

Now sure, this approximation is great and all, but one obvious problem is the larger our interval is the messier things could get. So one good countermeasure is to break up our entire big interval into smaller intervals, then do the rule above *over* and *over* and so on. That way, we get an even better approximation!

So afterwards, things instead look like this:

[image]

And of course you can guess that more trapezoids (aka more "partitions") means a better approximation.