# Definite integral approximation using Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, approximation

By simply drawing a graph of the function, I can find that whenever the function is concave up, the trapezoidal rule gives me a definite integral approximation larger than the actual integral of the function;whenever the function is concave down, the trapezoidal rule gives me a definite integral approximation smaller than the actual integral of the function. Is there any way to prove it true other than drawing out the function graph?

Comment: So, what you're trying to prove is: If a curve is concave up, then any line segment connecting two points of the curve goes below the curve, and _vice versa_.

Comment: Do you know the [error involved in trapezoidal rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535304/72031)? The error expression gives the conclusion directly.